# PuTTY and PowerTerm scripting Problem, Open a just in time URL via Samba share

Tags: terminal, scripting, samba, putty

I'm sshing into a fedora server using Powerterm (an expensive overly priced, license based, terminal emulator). The server uses an ancient form of (what I'm told is similar to) cobalt. I have no control over the server's programming but I'd like at least to not have to pay hundreds of dollars for a PuTTY like terminal emulator every time Windows changes their OS.

The software on the server is capable of building spreadsheets and exporting to Excel on a Windows machine via a samba share, but I can't seem to get that to work using PuTTY. I've logged the hidden command that the server sends to PowerTerm and it looks like this

```
_[P$sExcel.psl "\\serverFQDN\user\spdsht123.xls"_[\
```

and this was logged in the SSH in/out along with octal stuffs

```
.......1.[1;1H.P

$sExcel.psl "\\s

erverFQDN\user\s

pdsht123.xls".\
```

The file gets built but doesn't run, understandably, b/c nothing is scripted on PuTTY to listen for that specific character/string (not sure which is which). There are 2 files on the server that may also come into play somewhere but I can't see the code so I'm just guessing, or possibly just a copy in case someone were to delete them.

```
[me@erver PSL]$ cat excel.psl
exec "excel.exe $p1"
[me@erver PSL]$ cat PT.psl
exec "$p1"
```

Putty Settings

```
SSH -p22
Backspace Key - Control-H
FKeys and Keypad - SCO
Translation is Default Latin-1, West Europe ISO-8859-1:1998
Terminal-type string sends ansi
```

Initially I thought I could forward and tunnel the smb ports but since the filename is sent by the server live at that minute I'd have to script PuTTY to listen for a specific string ie. _[P$sExcel.psl and open the file using the default windows program associated with the URL. Then I noticed that PuTTY doesn't support this and I've tried countless PuTTY forks to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

These PSL files are specific to PowerTerm Pro so you're unlikely to get them to work with anything except that product.

http://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/psl

Basically what happens is the PSL file is pushed through the PowerTerm shell to your local computer where the command(s) inside it are executed locally on your computer. This command:

```
$sExcel.psl "\\s

erverFQDN\user\s

pdsht123.xls".\
```

Is actually doing this:

```
exec "excel.exe \\serverFQDN\user\spdsht123.xls"
```

So what are your options?

#### 1. open the file manually

This runs Excel and then tells it to open the file at `\\serverFQDN\user\spdsht123.xls`.

You can manually go to this path and just run these files yourself in Windows Explorer:

```
\\serverFQDN\user\spdsht123.xls
```

#### 2. This isn't possible in PuTTY

This capability will apparently never be implemented in PuTTY. It's discussed here in this post titled: [Escape sequence to execute command on the client side](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/osc.html).

#### 3. DoIt

You can use a tool called `DoIt` which you can use in a similar fashion to PowerTerm. You can [read more about it here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/doit/). DoIt is classified as a remote-execution daemon for Windows.